# FwpmFilterAdd0 failed (-2144206813)

Tags: c++, winapi, window, firewall, wfp

I copied the sample program from WFP documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fwpmu/nf-fwpmu-fwpmtransactionbegin0

I am using VS 2015.

Here is the output:

```
Opening filter engine.
Adding filter to permit traffic for Application 1.
FwpmFilterAdd0 failed (-2144206813).
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Can somebody help figure out the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer:

```
fwpFilter.displayData.name = L"some data";
```

This line was missing in the documentation.